# Test if a command has been defined by another package

Tags: macros

I normally use the LaTeX `\newcommand` to define macros. However, when using delimited macros I use `\def`. Is there a way that I can get LaTeX to trigger an error if the command defined by `\def` is being re-defined by another package, i.e, if someone tries to re-define the command a LaTeX error message is triggered.

Comment: Do you want to check whether a command is already defined (which is what all the answers are about), or do you want to make it impossible for someone else to overwrite your definitions?

Comment: Indeed, half of the answers are answering one of these questions and half the other.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

TeX does not provide anything similar to `\newcommand` but you can emulate it as shown in the minimal below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\test@{}
\def\test@[#1][#2][#3][#4]{%
  ....
}

\newcommand\test@{}
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

By defining first the command using `\newcommand` and then overriding it with a `\def` you ensure that LaTeX issues an error if a command with such a name has been defined earlier.

Comment: I'm no expert of LaTeX internals, but as far as I can understand, it does not keep track which commands are already defined. Your example would fail to compile even without the first `\newcommand`.

Comment: @Caramdir Why you say the code will not compile? As shown it correctly triggers an error, when you attempt to redefine it for the third time.

Comment: This is what I mean. But it triggers the same error if you remove the first `\newcommand`. So you don't need to tell LaTeX  which commands you have defined.

Comment: @Caramdir true, but if you add it, it will also let you know if it was defined earlier (similar to your answer).

Comment: @Caramdir: I also use this form of definition for my user level macros which require a parameter text. The first `\newcommand` triggers an error if the command is already defined. This is what the OP should use, but there is not way to protect that macro from future redefinitions.

Comment: @Martin: All I wanted to point out, that the sentence “using \newcommand [...] you ensure that LaTeX knows that a command with such a name has been defined” is misleading.

Comment: @Caramdir, @Yiannis: I edited the answer, hope it's not misleading anymore.

Answer (score 28):

For what it's worth, I think that Yiannis' answer (using `\newcommand` before `\def`) is the best way to do it, or at least the simplest.

e-TeX provides two new primitives to check if a control sequence is defined.

- `\ifdefined\cs` tests if `\cs` is a defined control sequence.
- `\ifcsname cs\endcsname` tests if `\cs` is a defined control sequence.

The `etoolbox` package contains more LaTeX-friendly wrappers.

- `\ifdef{\cs}{true}{false}` expands to `true` if `\cs` is defined, `false` otherwise.
- `\ifcsdef{cs}{true}{false}` is similar but for control sequence names.
- `\ifundef{\cs}{true}{false}` is similar to the negation of `\ifdef` except that control sequences that have been `\let` to `\relax` are considered undefined.
- `\ifcsundef{cs}{true}{false}` is similar but for control sequence names.

`etoolbox` also contains other useful tests, for example if a control sequence is a macro.

Having `\ifundef` and `\ifcsundef` check if a command is `\relax` may seem odd at first. However, LaTeX's `\@ifundefined` compares `\csname cs\endcsname` to `\relax`. The reason for this is that when TeX constructs a control sequence via `\csname ...\endcsname` that it has not seen before, it gives it the value of `\relax`. This has the downside that there's no way to differentiate between the name of a control sequence that is undefined and one that has been `\let` to `\relax`. `\ifcsundef` was designed to be a drop-in replacement for the LaTeX kernel's `\@ifundefined`.

**Edit:**
I just read Caramdir's comment. There's no good way to prevent another package from redefining a command you define. One possible way around this is to use `\AtBeginDocument{\def\cs{...}}` to define a macro later than most other macros, but this is not foolproof. Another package can do the same thing and the user can redefine any macro at any time.

Comment: +1. There are further examples of why the e-TeX way of doing it is good at [this TeX FAQ](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=isdef). In particular avoiding littering TeX's memory space with lots of unnecessary `\relax`es could be a good thing

Comment: @TH Your first two statements (about `\ifdefined` and `\ifcsname`) aren't precise. `\ifdefined a` returns `true` but `a` isn't a control sequence.

Comment: @Ahmed: You're correct that `\ifdefined` actually tests if the following token is defined (although I'm not sure what its utility is other than testing for control sequences). What was imprecise about the `\ifcsname` statement? The documentation says, "True if the control sequence `\csname...\endcsname` would be defined; creates no new hash table entry."

Answer (score 13):

It is technically impossible to protect a macro name (command sequence) from future redefinitions or trigger an error when it is redefined. TeX doesn't even protect its internal command and allows you to redefine them as well. This is by design.

You can however check at certain points (like at-begin-document) if your definition is still active and trigger an error otherwise:

```
% Inside your package
\newcommand*\mymcd{}% raises an error if the command is already defined
\def\mycmd ... { ... }  % Real definition of macro with parameter text
\let\my@cmd\mycmd  % Save macro away
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \ifx\mycmd\my@cmd\else
     \PackageError{mypackage}{Macro \string\mycmd\space got redefined!}{}%
  \fi
}
```

Answer (score 5):

No, `\def` is a TeX primitive and is destructive.  And this is one reason LaTeX has `\newcommand`.  If you and other package authors use `\newcommand`, then you will be warned against redefining each other's code.  But even then, there is `\renewcommand` to get around that problem if you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a generalization of Martin Scharrer's scheme. We introduce two commands `\cmddef` and `\robustcmddef` for defining simple and robust commands that can be tested anywhere for consistency/preservation. This is taken from *ltxtools-base* package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catoptions}
\makeatletter
\robust@def*\cmddef@teststcl#1{\cpt@testst{\cpt@testcl{#1}}}
\robust@def*\cmddef{\cmddef@teststcl{\cmd@def@\relax}}
\robust@def*\robustcmddef{\cmddef@teststcl{\cmd@def@\protected}}
\new@def\cmd@def@#1#2{%
  \ifcpt@st\let\l@ngrel@x\relax\else\let\l@ngrel@x\long\fi
  \ifcpt@cl\let\gl@balrel@x\global\else\let\gl@balrel@x\relax\fi
  \ifescapedTF{#2}{}{\cpt@notescapederr{#2}}%
  \ifdefTF#2{%
    \@latex@error{Command '\string#2' already defined}\@ehd
    \def\@tempa{\undefcs\@tempb}%
  }{%
    \def\@tempa{%
      \gl@balrel@x\let#2\@tempb
      \gl@balrel@x\letcsntocs{@test@command@\cptremovescape#2}#2%
      \undefcs\@tempb
    }%
  }%
  \afterassignment\@tempa
  \l@ngrel@x#1\def\@tempb
} 
\new@def\testcommand#1{%
  \ifescapedTF{#1}{}{\cpt@notescapederr{#1}}%
  \cptexpanded{%
    \ifmacroFT#1{%
      \noexpand\@secondoftwo
    }{%
      \expandafter\noexpand\csname @\expandafter\ifxTF
        \csname @test@command@\cptremovescape#1\endcsname
        #1{first}{second}oftwo\endcsname
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother
```

Tests:

```
\begin{document}
\def\y#1{Command `\string\x' has#1 changed}
\begingroup\tt
% Define command \x (* -> short; ! -> global):
\cmddef*!\x#1{#1}
% Test if command \x has changed since definition:
\testcommand\x{\y{n't}}{\y{}}
% Redefine command \x with \def:
\def\x{}
\par\medskip
% Test if command \x has changed since definition with \cmddef:
\testcommand\x{\y{n't}}{\y{}}
% The next one will produce and error:
% \cmddef!\x#1{#1}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```