# Name collision in package development

Tags: package-writing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [choosing macro names so as to avoid namespace conflicts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43674/choosing-macro-names-so-as-to-avoid-namespace-conflicts)

How package developer find out whether other packages already used a specific command name or not? How do they avoid name collision?

Comment: We've had variants of this question before.  Take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43674/86 (and the linked questions) and see if that answers your question.  If not, please explain a little more fully what it is you want to know.

Comment: To avoid issues like that, normally package writers would use some sort of prefix like `REZAenvi` or something like that. Something that identifies you as the writer.