# Shorthand for variables lead to name clash

Tags: macros, best-practices

In formulas I need often the same constants and variables with lot of "make-up".

I want to have readable and maintainable LaTeX code, so I thought about writing  `\newcommand`s like

```
\newcommand*{\Cref}{C_{\textrm{ref}}} %very short example
..
\[ \Cref \cdot U = Q \]
```

But `\Cref` is already in use by `\usepackage{cleveref}` and so on …

Finally I run quickly out of short, nice commands.

I am looking for someone who has had the same problem and had a brilliant idea.

Comment: You *might* make `\Cref` doing different things in math mode and in text mode, but this is not recommendable. I see no solution other than renaming the shorthand to, say, `\sCref` ("s" for subscript).

Comment: _Or_ you can rename the original `\Cref` to for example `\Cleveref` and then use your own `\Cref`. _Or_ you redefine `\Cref` in a way that when called `\Cref{}` it expands to `C_{\textrm{ref}}` otherwose the original definition is used.

Comment: You could have a single shortcut command with a list of possible names, so for example `\scut{Cref}` might expand to `C_{\textrm{ref}}`. Would this make sense?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I'd recommend none of your suggestions; the first is confusing, the second conceptually wrong as it gives a command different semantic values. In LaTeX the command ``\\`` can have several different expansions, but it *always* means "end a line here", at the user level.

Comment: I usually write `\newcommand{myfoo}{...}`. Then I know the command is mine, and won't accidentally conflict with something already defined. That's sometimes worth doing even if `myfoo` just wraps `foo `- so you can easily change foo behavior later.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Defining `\Cref` so that it does different things in different contexts (for instance if it has an empty argument or not, or if it is in math or text mode) is definitely not recommendable, as it is confusing.

You can define a "shortcut" producing command:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\scut}[1]{\@nameuse{myscut@#1}}
\newcommand{\defineshortcut}[2]{\global\@namedef{myscut@#1}{#2}}
\makeatother
```

Then you can set in your preamble

```
\defineshortcut{Cref}{C_{\textnormal{ref}}}
```

and use `\scut{Cref}` in your document. You can even say

```
\defineshortcut{C_ref}{C_{\textnormal{ref}}}
```

and use `\scut{C_ref}`, if you prefer.

If `\scut` is perceived as too long, one can use a shorter sequence; `\s` is free, while `\S` prints § (so it could be redefined, though with care, because some document could use the original command).

---

One can use a "one character shortcut", for instance `|` or `"` (if `babel` is not used); the following definitions allow also for "parameterized" shortcuts with the same syntax as `\newcommand`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\scut}[1]{\@nameuse{myscut@shortcut@#1}}
\newcommand{\defineshortcut}[1]{\expandafter\newcommand\csname myscut@shortcut@#1\endcsname}
\newcommand{\useshortcutsymbol}[1]{%
  \global\expandafter\chardef\csname myscut@catcode@#1\endcsname\catcode`#1\relax
  \catcode`#1=\active
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`#1\relax
  \lowercase{\endgroup\def~##1~}{\@nameuse{myscut@shortcut@##1}}}
\newcommand{\undefineshortcutsymbol}[1]{%
  \catcode`#1\csname myscut@catcode@\string#1\endcsname}
\makeatother

\defineshortcut{C}[1]{C_\textnormal{#1}}
\defineshortcut{Cref}{C_\textnormal{ref}}

\begin{document}
\useshortcutsymbol{|}

$\scut{C}{ref}\quad\scut{Cref}$

$|C|{ref}\quad|Cref|$

\undefineshortcutsymbol{|}

$|C|$

\end{document}
```

However I wouldn't use this kind of "too short" shortcuts, which are error prone. The `\useshortcut` command should receive a *non special* ASCII character as its argument; high bit set characters are definitely not safe, because they are treated differently in different encodings.

Comment: Nice! But, even if using a one-letter command like `\q`, it's still four extra characters to type for each shortcut, three of which are difficult to access on some keyboards. What would the code look like to make the string, say, `°xyz` expand to `\scut{xyz}`? Also, is it possible to do "parametric" shortcuts with your approach?

Comment: That looks good. We only need something shorter then `\scut`... is `\S` still free?

Comment: Thank you, this is awesome! I understand that the braces in `|{ref}` are required because `\scut` simply calls `\@nameuse`.? How would you define `\scut` so that it uses all subsequent letter characters as shortcut name?

Comment: @user946850 A final delimiter is necessary; it *might* be a space, but if you have `|Cref` at the end of a line TeX would not see a space and havoc would ensue.

Comment: @egreg: Why is using the "end of line" as potential delimiter so difficult? I thought that TeX interprets EOL + all subsequent spaces as a single space...

Comment: @user946850 A single EOL is considered equivalent to a space as far as typesetting is concerned, but it is a different token than a space. A *very* slow routine should be used to test what follows.

Comment: @egreg: I think I understand your point. Would it be possible to allow four delimiters -- space, EOL, `[` and `{` -- and issue a high-level error in `\scut` if the parameter happens to contain non-letter tokens?

Comment: @egreg: `xparse` seems to offer this facility at a high level: "`u` -- Reads an argument “until” <tokens> are encountered, where the desired <tokens> are given as an argument to the speciﬁer: `u{<tokens>}`.". The check for non-letter tokens (or, more generally, for undefined shortcuts) should be doable with `\ifcsdef` from `etoolbox`.?

Comment: The facility offered by `xparse` is no different from the primitive one available in TeX. Your proposal for the four delimiters is painfully slow and fragile.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple approach: make a command for the subscripted "ref".

```
 \newcommand*\sref{_{\textrm{ref}}}
```

This makes the "ref" akin to a diacritic or operator: This makes it easier to systematically refer to "ref"-variables in your text. I routinely do the same to define transposes and hermitian adjoints, as in

```
 \newcommand*\trans{^{\textsf{T}}}
 \newcommand*\herm{^\dagger}
```

Answer (score 3):

In other programming languages this is usually solved using [namespaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace#Namespaces_in_Programming_Languages). For LaTeX, there is the [namespc](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/namespc) package which provides

> rudimentary C++-like namespaces in LaTeX.

Example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{namespc}
\usepackage{cleveref}
%
\newcommand{\overwritecommand}[1]{\let#1\undefined\newcommand{#1}}
%
\begin{document}
  \section{First section}
  \label{sec:first}

  \namespace{shortcuts}{%
    \overwritecommand{\Cref}{mycref}
  }{}

  This is the original definition: \Cref{sec:first}

  \begin{shortcuts}
    This is used from within the ``shortcuts'' environment: \Cref
  \end{shortcuts}

  \begin{align*}
    \usingnamespace{shortcuts}
    \text{Equation} = \text{\Cref}
  \end{align*}

  This is to access the macro explicitly: \::shortcuts::Cref::
\end{document}
```

[image]

To be honest, I have found it only through a dedicated search, I have never seen it in use before. I am going to be using it from now on for the problem you described.