# Which commands exist to define new commands?

Tags: macros, tex-core

Which commands are there that one can use to define new commands in (La)TeX?

There are: `\let`, `\def`, `\[re]newcommand[*]`, `\DeclareRobustCommand[*]`, *and* ...?

(And I've seen things like `\DeclareMathOperator`.)

Comment: I think there is only `\def` which defines a new command. `\let` just assigns a new name. All the others are “only” wrappers around `\def`, of which there can be arbitrarily many.

Comment: @canaaerus I suspected something like that. But which well-known (or not so well-known) wrappers are there?

Comment: @LoverofStructure i think your question is rather vague. Just consider LaTeX2e's `\newcounter`. It sets up a new counter but also defines a command called \thecounter which prints the counter. So for a complete answer one would have to list a lot of macros.

Comment: @bloodworks Thanks for your contribution; `\thecounter` without any space ... that's weird. If a comprehensive list is long, so be it :-)

Comment: @LoverofStructure It would be useful to know if you are talking about primitives or higher-level wrappers, and also if you mean just macros or other cases (_e.g._ do `\chardef` or `\toksdef` count?).

Comment: @JosephWright I see - it looks like there are more details to be spceified than I thought. I suppose I could try and delimit my question, but I'd probably be using the notions of tokens, catcodes, and the hashtable of definitions incorrectly. What about me letting others answer in either the most general way or edit down my question to delimit its scope? The former might be better from an informational perspective.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The LaTeX "official" interface provides

```
\newcommand
\renewcommand
\providecommand

\newlength
\newsavebox

\newenvironment
\renewenvironment
\newtheorem

\newcounter
```

All these commands define one or more commands (some only for internal usage) and provide tests for avoiding clobbering of existing commands. There's also `\newfont`, but its usage is deprecated.

The kernel has many other command-defining macros:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand

\DeclareTextCommand
\DeclareTextCommandDefault
\DeclareTextSymbol
\DeclareTextSymbolDefault
\DeclareTextAccent
\DeclareTextComposite
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand

\DeclareMathSymbol
\DeclareMathAccent
\DeclareMathDelimiter

\protected@edef
```

Of these, only the first one is commonly used in LaTeX programming (it shouldn't be used indiscriminately as a replacement of `\newcommand`, though). The last is very useful in core LaTeX programming.

Some additional packages provide new functions:

```
\DeclareMathOperator      (amsmath)
\DeclarePairedDelimiter   (mathtools)
```

are commonly found, but there are scores of other command-defining functions in the hundreds of packages around.

---

Another commonly used utility for defining commands is the primitive `\let`, that "copies" the current meaning of a token into a control sequence, allowing for "redefining a macro in terms of itself". However, for the nonexpert (and also the expert) programmer, the

```
\LetLtxMacro
```

provided by the `letltxmacro` package by H. Oberdiek is a recommended replacement.

---

The `etoolbox` package provides another set

```
\newrobustcmd
\renewrobustcmd
\providerobustcmd
```

(look at the documentation for a description).

---

Eventually, all of these command-defining functions boil down to the primitive commands

```
\def
\gdef
\edef
\xdef

\let
\futurelet

\chardef
\mathchardef    
\countdef
\dimendef
\skipdef
\muskipdef
\toksdef

\font
\read
```

but a description of these would require writing a chapter of a book; refer to the TeXbook or to [TeX by Topic](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/plain/texbytopic/TeXbyTopic.pdf)

Comment: as always very nice!

Comment: And note that many of these have starred variants.